# How to make elasticsearch add the timestamp field to every document in all indices?

Tags: mapping, timestamp, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch experts,

I have been unable to find a simple way to just tell ElasticSearch to insert the _timestamp field for all the documents that are added in all the indices (and all document types).

I see an example for specific types:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/timestamp-field/

and also see an example for all indices for a specific type (using _all):
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/

but I am unable to find any documentation on adding it by default for all documents that get added irrespective of the index and type.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-create-index.html

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do this by providing it when creating your index.

```
$curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test -d '{
"settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 1
},
"mappings" : {
    "_default_":{
        "_timestamp" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "store" : true
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

That will then automatically create a [_timestamp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) for all stuff that you put in the index.
Then after indexing something when requesting the _timestamp field it will be returned.

Comment: This worked. Thanks Marcus. I take it that you cannot define this as a global setting for all indices which is ok. For anyone who wants to try this using elasticsearch head plug-in, make sure you specify POST request and not GET.

Comment: @Marcus - I have tried this. I can't see _timestamp in my Kibana3 visualization the same way I see _id, _index and _type. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Remember that _timestamp must be requested as a field for it to be returned when querying. Add {"fields":"_timestamp"}.

Comment: Also be advised that if records have already been written on that index a mapping will not work, so be sure to create a mapping before writing records on that index, otherwise you will get an error when setting that store type to true.  -> {"error":"RemoteTransportException[[Damion Hellstrom][inet[/x.x.x.x:y]][indices:admin/mapping/put]]; nested: MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [_timestamp] has different store values]}]; ","status":400}"

Comment: This have been deprecated. Please use this with caution. Best will be to create a date field of your own.

Comment: This in 7.2 returns error:

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_default_ : {_timestamp={store=true, enabled=true}}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_default_ : {_timestamp={store=true, enabled=true}}]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_default_ : {_timestamp={store=true, enabled=true}}]"}},"status":400}

Comment: Update for 2021 in my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66958236/8160318).

Comment: @JoeSorocin your solution will work (ES 7.13), but the `created_at` field will be updated at every item indexing, since the `ctx` will not have that field at the next run of the processor (see my comment to your answer). Any hint for that?

Answer (score 63):

Elasticsearch used to support automatically adding timestamps to documents being indexed, but [**deprecated** this feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-timestamp-field.html) in 2.0.0

From the version 5.5 [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_literal__timestamp_literal_and_literal__ttl_literal):

> The _timestamp and _ttl fields were deprecated and are now removed. As a replacement for _timestamp, **you should populate a regular date field with the current timestamp on application side**.

Comment: Update for 2021 in my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66958236/8160318).

Answer (score 29):

Adding another way to get indexing timestamp. Hope this may help someone.

**Ingest pipeline** can be used to add timestamp when document is indexed. Here, is a sample example:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/indexed_at
{
  "description": "Adds indexed_at timestamp to documents",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_source.indexed_at",
        "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Earlier, elastic search was using named-pipelines because of which 'pipeline' param needs to be specified in the elastic search endpoint which is used to write/index documents. (Ref: [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/default-ingest-pipeline-for-index/123511/3)) This was bit troublesome as you would need to make changes in endpoints on application side.

With Elastic search version >= 6.5, you can now specify a default pipeline for an index using `index.default_pipeline` settings. (Refer [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings) for details)

Here is the to set default pipeline:

```
PUT ms-test/_settings
{
  "index.default_pipeline": "indexed_at"
}
```

I haven't tried out yet, as didn't upgraded to ES 6.5, but above command should work.

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of [default index pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings), leverage the [script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html), and thus emulate the `auto_now_add` functionality you may know from [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield) and `DEFAULT GETDATE()` from [SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp).

The process of adding a default `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` date goes like this:

**1. Create the [pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) and specify which indices it'll be allowed to run on:**

```json
PUT _ingest/pipeline/auto_now_add
{
  "description": "Assigns the current date if not yet present and if the index name is whitelisted",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          // skip if not whitelisted
          if (![ "myindex",
                 "logs-index",
                 "..."
              ].contains(ctx['_index'])) { return; }
          
          // don't overwrite if present
          if (ctx['created_at'] != null) { return; }
          
          ctx['created_at'] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*Side note: the ingest processor's Painless script context is documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-ingest-processor-context.html).*

**2. Update the `default_pipeline` setting in *all* of your indices:**

```json
PUT _all/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "default_pipeline": "auto_now_add"
  }
}
```

Side note: you can restrict the target indices using the [multi-target syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html):

```json
PUT myindex,logs-2021-*/_settings?allow_no_indices=true
{
  "index": {
    "default_pipeline": "auto_now_add"
  }
}
```

**3. Ingest a document to one of the configured indices:**

```json
PUT myindex/_doc/1
{
  "abc": "def"
}
```

**4. Verify that the date string has been added:**

```json
GET myindex/_search
```

Comment: This works, but the check`if (ctx['created_at'] != null) { return; }` will not work, since the `ctx` will not have this property created by the processor at the next run.

Comment: I reckon `ctx` *should* be present at all times but if it's not, you can additionally check `if (ctx != null && ...)` just to be sure.

Comment: So in the tests I did even when `ctx != null`you will get `ctx['created_at']==null` when you update an object with the same `_id`. At least, if I did not anything wrong

Comment: Can you open another SO question for this? Not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean that there is no way to check if the field `created_at` previously existed, if you create it in a processor script, because that field lives only in the output, not in the index.

Comment: I see. You should also have access to `ctx._source` to peek into the actual underlying values.

Comment: Thanks, here my full question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68286853/elasticsearch-ingest-pipeline-create-and-update-timestamp-field

Answer (score 1):

An example for ElasticSearch 6.6.2 in Python 3:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(hosts=["localhost"])

timestamp_pipeline_setting = {
  "description": "insert timestamp field for all documents",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "ingest_timestamp",
        "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}

es.ingest.put_pipeline("timestamp_pipeline", timestamp_pipeline_setting)

conf = {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 2,
        "number_of_replicas": 1,
        "default_pipeline": "timestamp_pipeline"
    },
    "mappings": {
        "articles":{
            "dynamic": "false",
            "_source" : {"enabled" : "true" },
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                },
                "content": {
                    "type": "text",
                },
            }
        }
    }
}

response = es.indices.create(
    index="articles_index",
    body=conf,
    ignore=400 # ignore 400 already exists code
)

print ('\nresponse:', response) 

doc = {
    'title': 'automatically adding a timestamp to documents',
    'content': 'prior to version 5 of Elasticsearch, documents had a metadata field called _timestamp. When enabled, this _timestamp was automatically added to every document. It would tell you the exact time a document had been indexed.',
}
res = es.index(index="articles_index", doc_type="articles", id=100001, body=doc)
print(res)

res = es.get(index="articles_index", doc_type="articles", id=100001)
print(res)
```

About ES 7.x, the example should work after removing the doc_type related parameters as it's not supported any more.

Answer (score -1):

first create index and properties of the index , such as field and datatype and then insert the data using the rest API.

below is the way to create index with the field properties.execute the following in kibana console

```
`PUT /vfq-jenkins
{
"mappings": {
"properties": {
"BUILD_NUMBER": { "type" : "double"},
"BUILD_ID" : { "type" : "double" },
"JOB_NAME" : { "type" : "text" },
"JOB_STATUS" : { "type" : "keyword" },
"time" : { "type" : "date" }
 }}}`
```

the next step is to insert the data into that index:

```
curl -u elastic:changeme -X POST http://elasticsearch:9200/vfq-jenkins/_doc/?pretty 
-H Content-Type: application/json -d '{ 
"BUILD_NUMBER":"83","BUILD_ID":"83","JOB_NAME":"OMS_LOG_ANA","JOB_STATUS":"SUCCESS" , 
"time" : "2019-09-08'T'12:39:00" }'
```