# Elasticsearch index last update time

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to retrieve from ElasticSearch information on when a specific index was last updated? 
My goal is to be able to tell when it was the last time that any documents were inserted/updated/deleted in the index. If this is not possible, is there something I can add in my index modification requests that will provide this information later on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make elasticsearch add the timestamp field to every document in all indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136138/how-to-make-elasticsearch-add-the-timestamp-field-to-every-document-in-all-indic)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the modification time from the [_timestamp](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html)

To make it easier to return the timestamp you can set up Elasticsearch to store it:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_mapping" -d'
{
  "mytype": {
      "_timestamp": {
          "enabled": "true",
          "store": "yes"
      }
  }
}'
```

If I insert a document and then query on it I get the timestamp:

```
 curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?pretty' -d '{
>  fields : ["_timestamp"],
>    "query": {
>     "query_string": { "query":"*"}
>    }
> }'
{
   "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
     "total" : 1,
     "max_score" : 1.0,
     "hits" : [ {
       "_index" : "myindex",
       "_type" : "mytype",
       "_id" : "1",
       "_score" : 1.0,
       "fields" : {
        "_timestamp" : 1417599223918
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

updating the existing document:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/1/_update" -d'
{
  "doc" : {
      "field1": "data",
      "field2": "more data"
  },
  "doc_as_upsert" : true
}'
```

Re-running the previous query shows me an updated timestamp:

```
  "fields" : {
    "_timestamp" : 1417599620167
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Olly. I tried this and indeed the timestamp get updated along with the document. But this is only half of what I need, since I want to get the timestamp of the document that was updated most recently. Is there an easy way to do this or I have to do a query for all documents with sorted timestamp and get the top result? Also, if a document is deleted from the index, there will be no timestamp to indicate that something has changed, correct?

Comment: I would do an aggregation that returns the max _timestamp. If you need the document too, you can run a second search that uses the timestamp. You're correct on the 2nd point, if the document is deleted you won't be able to search for it.

Comment: I need only the timestamp. Using the max aggregation it worked like a charm. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is deprecated in 2.0, is there any other way to get an auto generated timestamp ?

Comment: Would love to find more about it. Here is one of the github threads that is tracking the same request: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13462

Comment: Deprecated feature, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43521153/2017567

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there are people who are looking for an equivalent, but here is a workaround using shards stats for > Elasticsearch 5 users: 
curl XGET http://localhost:9200/_stats?level=shards

As you'll see, you have some informations per indices, commits and/or flushs that you might use to see if the indice changed (or not).

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 4):

Just looked into a solution for this problem. Recent Elasticsearch versions have a `<index>/_recovery` API.

This returns a list of shards and a field called `stop_time_in_millis` which looks like it is a timestamp for the last write to that shard.

Comment: I don't know why anyone would down vote this.  It solves the OP's problem exactly.  curl localhost:9200/my-index/_recovery?pretty | jq . | grep stop | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | tail -1

Comment: @WayneWalker It doesn't.. shard action != document action and shard that was used for the index is not exclusive to the index. (Old) shards may still be moved (e.g. when adding an elastic node). Easiest Python solution is es.search(index='my_index', size=1, sort='my_timestamp:desc' )

Comment: This is incorrect. It will be reset on restart, which means unupdated index will essentially just show server uptime

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that could suffice in some use cases, could also be to look at the files that elastic search use to store its data, and sort those based on modification time, e.g.:

sudo find /var/lib/elasticsearch/ -type f -exec stat -c "%y - %n" {} ; | sort -k 1,2

This would give a conservative estimate, in the sense that data is certainly not modified later than the file with the latest timestamp.