# How to get the last update of the index in elasticsearch

Tags: search, indexing, full-text-search, elasticsearch

How can I find datetime of last update of the elsasticsearch index?
[Elasticsearch index last update time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255596/elasticsearch-index-last-update-time) I tried to follow the example , but nothing happened .

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_mapping'
{"haystack":{"mappings":{"modelresult":{"_all":{"auto_boost":true},"_boost":{"name":"boost","null_value":1.0},"properties":{"act_name":{"type":"string","boost":1.3,"index_analyzer":"index_ngram","search_analyzer":"search_ngram"},"django_ct":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","include_in_all":false},"django_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","include_in_all":false},"hometown":{"type":"string","boost":0.9,"index_analyzer":"index_ngram","search_analyzer":"search_ngram"},"id":{"type":"string"},"text":{"type":"string","analyzer":"ngram_analyzer"}}},"mytype":{"_timestamp":{"enabled":true,"store":true},"properties":{}}}}}

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search -d '{
  "size": 1,
  "sort": {
    "_timestamp": "desc"
  },
  "fields": [
    "_timestamp"
  ]
}'
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":99,"max_score":null,"hits":[{"_index":"haystack","_type":"modelresult","_id":"account.user.96","_score":null,"sort":[-9223372036854775808]}]}}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, what you need to do is to proceed like in that linked question and enable the [`_timestamp` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) in your mapping.

```
{
    "modelresult" : {
        "_timestamp" : { "enabled" : true }
    }
}
```

Then you can query your index for a single document with the most recent timestamp like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/haystack/modelresult/_search -d '{
  "size": 1,
  "sort": {
    "_timestamp": "desc"
  },
  "fields": [
    "_timestamp"
  ]
}'
```

Comment: which means your_type? Where can I see it?

Comment: It's the name of your mapping type, but since it wasn't mentioned in your question, I just added a placeholder. You may replace it with whatever mapping type name you have.

Comment: I added requests to the question

Comment: Have you re-indexed your data after adding the `_timestamp` field?

Comment: Yes,  I did it. The result has not changed.

Comment: Can you provide the steps you did, with the exact index and type names you've used in your queries?

Comment: No I can not. I use the haystack with django and I do not see direct requests .