# Is there a good way to track the timestamp when a particular Elastic Search Index gets updated?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a good way to track when a particular index/type is updated with new documents. I have use-case where we constantly update an index/type with new documents and was wondering what is the recommended way to go about the same.
[Link to a similar question asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255596/elasticsearch-index-last-update-time)

I do understand the concept as to how the documents are stored and update in a distributed system(i.e. keeping track of timestamp wrt each document). But, was wondering, whats the recommended way of knowing when was the index updated because of a change, or does that not make any logical sense ?

Comment: By "index updated", do you simply mean when a new document gets indexed into the index, or could it also be any other operation such as creating/updating a mapping?

Comment: @Val apologies for not being descriptive. Only "when a new document is indexed or an existing document is updated". I know it makes sense to capture the 'timestamp' information for each document but what if one is only interested in the at index level.

Comment: There is nothing supporting this that I know of. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10379) that could potentially support what you're expecting, though.

Comment: @val yup i saw that, forgot to attach it to the question. So, i guess no work around for now.