# Last updated time for an index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use case where I ran a batch code to first create and then subsequently update my index in elasticsearch.

My program crashed pre-maturedly and now I want to know what was the last time that an update was made to my elasticsearch index.

Is there any api which could give me the information for the last update time of the index.

I have not been able to find any such resources. I looked specifically in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html

and tried,

```
curl http://{myhost}/{indexName}/_stats
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255596/elasticsearch-index-last-update-time

Comment: This requires prior mapping. I was looking for something more on the settings end of elasticsearch.