# Timestamp not appearing in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'm pretty new to Kibana and just set up an instance to look at some ElasticSearch data.

I have one index in Elastic Search, which has a few fields including _timestamp. When I go to the 'Discover' tab and look at my documents, each have the _timestamp field but with a yellow warning next to the field saying "No cached mapping for this field". As a result, I can't seem to sort/filter by time.

When I try and create a new index pattern and click on "Index contains time-based events", the 'Time-field name' dropdown doesn't contain anything.

Is there something else I need to do to get Kibana to recognise the _timestamp field?

I'm using Kibana 4.0.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You'll need to take these quick steps first :

1. Go to *Settings → Advanced*.
2. Edit the **metaFields** and add "_timestamp". Hit save.
3. Now go back to *Settings → Indices* and **_timestamp** will be available in the drop-down list for "Time-field name".

[image: Kibana 4 Advanced Settings metaFields]

Comment: Atention, this is now deprecated!

Comment: @Anoyz Please specify version of Kibana as of which it's deprecated. Thanks.

Comment: @Anoyz Definitely not. I think you're confusing two separate issues.

Comment: Yeah, I still had to do this with Kibana 4

Comment: The `_timestamp` field itself is deprecated as of ES 2.0, but this method in kibana is not deprecated.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions you are required to specify the date field before you send your data.

Your date field must be in a standard format such as miliseconds after Epoch (long number) or - just as suggested by MrE - in ISO8601.
See more info here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

Again, before you send your data to the index, you must specify the mapping for this field. In python:

```
import requests
mapping = '{"mappings": {"your_index": {"properties": {"your_timestamp_field": { "type": "date" }}}}}'
requests.put('http://yourserver/your_index', data=mapping)
...
send_data()
```

Answer (score 2):

My es version is 2.2.0

You have to the right schema. 
I follow the [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/getting-started.html) 
Eg:

```
 {
        "memory": INT,
        "geo.coordinates": "geo_point"
        "@timestamp": "date"
    }
```

If you have the @timestamp, you will see the [image]

> ps: if your schema doesn't have "date" field, do not check "Index
>   contains time-based events

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is obsolete as of Kibana 2.0

you should use a simple `date` field in your data and set it explicitly using either a timestamp, or a date string in ISO 8601 format.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

you also need to set a mapping to date BEFORE you start sending data apparently.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "date" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: This is a little late to ask this question, but by 'date' field, do you mean a field with the name 'date', or simply a field that has a type of 'date'?  I'm having the same problem as this post, but as you said, the _timestamp thing has been deprecated.

Comment: a date type field which you can call date but that's for convenjence

Comment: Hmm.  I have a few fields defined that are of type date, but they don't show up in the Time-field name box in Kibana 4.  I'll have to keep digging.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->Indices, select your index, and click the yellow "refresh" icon.  That will get rid of the warning, and perhaps make the field available in your visualization.

Comment: Thanks Alain, but unfortunately that didn't work (no change when I hit the refresh icon).. I might have set up the original timestamp field incorrectly (I followed instructions on another question, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136138/how-to-make-elasticsearch-add-the-timestamp-field-to-every-document-in-all-indic).

Comment: Yes I think I set _timestamp as stored and enabled when I first created the index. Is there a way to check? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: You can pull the mapping with curl and it will tell you.