# How to add "updatedAt" timestamp to elasticsearch documents

Tags: elasticsearch, iso8601, elasticsearch-painless

I want to ensure that all documents of a certain doc_type have a "updatedAt" timestamp (ISO 8601) that gets updated whenever the document is updated.  It needs to be a server-side timestamp as I don't know if I can trust that all of the clients times are in sync.

I use an ingest pipeline to add "createdAt" timestamps, but it seems that pipelines are not supported using the update API.

I've tried using update scripts (using the newly available 'ctx._now' value), but cannot get the parsing into ISO 8601 working.  Further, I'm not sure that update scripts are the most maintainable way of doing this since every update type would require a custom script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make elasticsearch add the timestamp field to every document in all indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136138/how-to-make-elasticsearch-add-the-timestamp-field-to-every-document-in-all-indic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my scripts I use following painless line to mark updatedAt timestamp:

```
ctx._source.updatedAt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(ctx._now), ZoneId.of("Z"));
```

Z zone id is for UTC timezone. The `updatedAt` field has date type set as `date`. What is weird is that just assigning `ctx._now` to field also works. But it then looks different in source than rest of my date fields so I prefer the above way to keep things consistent.

Comment: use this instead of above 
   ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis()), ZoneId.of(\"Z\"))