# Date format issue when reading data from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i'm reading data from elasticsearch . when i visualize date format on kibana it shows 
Date    Aug 5, 2020 @ 23:00:00.000     => so it's correct 
but when i'm reading it from elasticsearch to do some machine learning , 
i noticed that date format is taken wrong 
Date   1.596665e+12

i'm collecting the content of the index into a dataframe with pyspark and i can do it in scala if there's any solution

`from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from pandasticsearch import Select

es = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200'],timeout=600)
documents = es.search(index='sub1',body={})

pandas_df = Select.from_dict(documents).to_pandas()
print(pandas_df)
'

it shows wrong date format , so how can i solve it ? any help ? 
thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.596665e+12` equals `1596665000000` which is a unix millisecond timestamp corresponding to  `Wednesday, August 5, 2020 10:03:20 PM` in GMT.

You've essentially got 3 options:

1. Use a `script_field` to [parse/convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45864252/8160318) the `ts` to a human-readable date. Note that you'll need to extract the script fields from the response b/c they're not part of the `_source`.
2. [Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21787689/8160318) the timestamps after you fetch the docs but before you load them into a df (preferably in a loop/list comprehension/map).
3. Reindex your data w/ already converted timestamps. This can be done from [inside of an `_update` script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47093742/8160318), you don't need to drop everything.

**UPDATE**

Implementation of point 2

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from datetime import datetime as dt


def convert_ts(hit):
    hit = hit['_source']

    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('date_field', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`date_field` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['date_field_as_date'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return hit


es = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200'], timeout=600)
documents = es.search(index='sub1', body={})['hits']['hits']
documents = [convert_ts(doc) for doc in documents]

print(documents)

# pandas etc ...
```

Comment: import datetime
print(
    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int("1284105682")
    ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
)
i found this but i don't know how to apply it on many columns 
cuz it's not a single variable 
i need to modify 6 columns .... !! help

Comment: Updated my answer. Good luck!