# how to auto generate and add current timestamp in Opensearch v2.7 document while inserting new documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I am using below index mapping to create index in opensearch v2.7 -

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 17,
        "number_of_replicas": 17
    },

    "mappings": {
      "_default_":{
        "_timestamp" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "store" : true
        }
     },
      "_meta": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "product": "my_product"

      },
      "properties": {      
        "region": {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "created_date" : {
           "type" : "date"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

It's failing with 400 bad request.

Also Checked Opensearch v2.7 documentation from https://opensearch.org/docs/2.7/im-plugin/index-templates/   but did not find anything of this sort.

There is stackoverflow ticket - [How to add default @timestamp to my elastic search data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53884110/how-to-add-default-timestamp-to-my-elastic-search-data)   but looks like its for Elasticsearch and not Opensearch.

Any way through which i can auto generate current timestamp and insert with every doc in opensearch?