# Elasticsearch: How to add "created_at" and "updated_at" timestamps?

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

I have a database where I should store `created_at` and `updated_at` fields for each document.

The `created_at` field should be created once on first document insert.

The `updated_at` field should be created on first document insert and should be updated via Bulk API on each update, even if none of the document fields are changed.

The question is: how to add those timestamps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make elasticsearch add the timestamp field to every document in all indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136138/how-to-make-elasticsearch-add-the-timestamp-field-to-every-document-in-all-indic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Elasticsearch used to have a feature to add these automatically, but it was removed in later versions to improve performance. You would have to add these fields to your mapping and then implement a process to set those fields. One way to do this is with an ingest pipeline, which someone explains [in the ES forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/creation-and-update-timestamps-for-each-doc/93456). You will want to check the docs for how to implement pipelines with your particular version of Elasticsearch.

Suggestion: You should always check the [forums](https://discuss.elastic.co/) for Elasticsearch questions. The community seems to be more active on there, and devs will also often respond to questions.

Comment: Unfortunately as for elasticsearch v7.2 I've not found any other way to add those timestamps but ingest pipelines and update/upsert scripts. Accepting this answer.