# Elasticsearch reindex only missing documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, reindex

I am trying to reindex an index of 200M of documents from cluster A to cluster B. I used the Reindex API with a remote source and everything worked fine. In the menwhile of my reindex some documents were added into the cluster A so I want to add them as well into the cluster B.

I launched again the reindex request but it seems that the reindex process is taking a lot, like if it was reindexing everything again.

My question is, is the cluster reindexing from scratch all the documents, even if they didn't change ?

My elasticsearch version is the 5.6

[image: Indexing rate]

[image: Document deletion rate]

Comment: you index is of type daily or you store all in the same index ?

Comment: it is all in the same index

Answer (score 4):

The elasticsearch does not know there is a change in the documents or not. So it tries to have each document completely in both indices. If you have a field like `insert_time` in your data, you can use reindex with query to limit the part of index of A to become reindex on B. This will let you use your older reindex and finish it faster. Reindex by query would be something like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "A",
    "query": {
       "range": {
          "insert_time": {
              "gt": "time you want"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "B"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Alessio Trivisonno  : You can use it by modifying the query to point to the added data

Comment: Thank you for your answers, as I don't have a timestamp value I couldn't use this solution. For the future it would be a good idea to add a default _timestamp as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136138/how-to-make-elasticsearch-add-the-timestamp-field-to-every-document-in-all-indic

Comment: You're Welcome my friend!